# Dependency injection of class with variadic template member function

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, variadic-templates

**Context:**
I have a third party logger class that has a variadic log function taking an arbitrary nr of parameters. 
In my code base I have several classes that need to log information. Instead of hardcoding this 3rd party logger class I want to be able to supply an instance through dependency injection. This way I can also supply for example a null object if I want to disable logging at run time.

**Example code:**

```
//third partycode
class Logger{
public:
    template<typename ...Ts>
    void Log(const char * format, Ts... params);
};

//own code
class NullLogger{
public:
    template<typename ...Ts>
    void Log(const char * format, Ts... params); // doesn't do actual logging
};

class SomeClass{
public:
    template<typename LOGGER>
    void SetLogger(std::shared_ptr<LOGGER> logger){ m_logger = logger;}

    void SomeFunction(){
        m_logger->Log("test {0},{1}", 42, 13.37);
    }
private:
    ??? m_logger;
};
```

**Question:**
How can I make above code work?

My requirements:

1. I do not want to make SomeClass a template class.
2. I can not change the third party Logger(I can choose a different design for my own NullLogger)
3. I want to be able to swap out the logger that is being used by SomeClass **at run time.**

Comment: You can do dependency injection only for virtual functions. So you can inherit NullLogger from Logger and provide a std::shared_ptr<Logger> instead. But it will not have effect. The Logger function will be called, because you can't make template functions virtual. So if you want a template function inject, then you can do it only in template class.

Comment: @armagedescu That is indeed the dilemma. If I make SomeClass a template class, I can no longer swap out loggers at runtime. It seems like this is a reasonable use case, so I was (and am still) hoping that there is some alternative design that I overlooked which fits my requirements.

Comment: @Antiro42 why would you swap loggers at runtime? This makes sense for testing purposes, in test cases.

Comment: @armagedescu Fair point, perhaps in the logger setting, swapping at run time is not that useful. Still curious if there is a way to do this. Would the situation be different if you know the arguments are in a limited set of types? (say int, bool, double, string). I can see you being able to break up a call into multiple calls to an overloaded function on some base class / interface class. but then you would have to reassemble these arguments again to call the third party logger in the derived class...

Comment: @Antiro42 You should keep in mind, in runtime there is no template. In runtime is template instances. But templates are instantiated at compile time. That's why you can't make a template on a virtual function. If you want really to hack your logger, you should not overwrite the function Log. It will take no effect since you call the base class. You should see what function is called by function Log in logger. And override that function if it is virtual. Otherwise you have no choice.

Comment: @Antiro42 Check the my answer

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to inject any dependence that is not designed to be injectable. Maybe logger is, you will try to see how Log function is implemented.
The Log function is template, so it can't be overridden now:

```cpp
//third partycode
class Logger{
public:
    template<typename ...Ts>
    void Log(const char * format, Ts... params);
};
```

What you should to is to check how the function Log is implemented

```cpp
    template<typename ...Ts>
    void Log(const char * format, Ts... params)
    {maybe it calls here any virtual_function(format, params...);}
```

If it calls any virtual function you can override it:

```cpp
//own code
class NullLogger: Logger{
public:
    virtual_function(const char * format, Ts... params); // override
};
```

Maybe there is another way, for instance you could provide any specific stream objects to be used by Logger.
So if you succeed with above you have everything injectable, otherwise there is no choice:

```cpp
class SomeClass{
public:
    void SetLogger(std::shared_ptr<Logger> logger){ m_logger = logger;}

    void SomeFunction(){
        m_logger->Log("test {0},{1}", 42, 13.37);
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Logger> m_logger;
};
```